# Update connected app using MetadataService (SOAP)

Tags: soap-api, connected-apps

I'm trying to update a connected app programatically using [MetadataService framwork](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls). I have no problem with create and delete connected app. Here is my code :

```
public class UpdateConnectedApps {
public static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService() {
      MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
      service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
      service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
      service.timeout_x = 40000;
      return service;
  }

    public static void updateConnectedApps() {
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();

    //build
    MetadataService.ConnectedApp build = new MetadataService.ConnectedApp();
    build.contactEmail = 'test@test.com';
    build.fullName = 'build2019aaa';
    build.label = 'ConnectedAppToUpdate';
    build.description = 'description';
    MetadataService.ConnectedAppOauthConfig buildo = new MetadataService.ConnectedAppOauthConfig();
    buildo.consumerKey = 'XXX';
    buildo.consumerSecret = 'VVV';
    buildo.callbackUrl = 'https://eu16.lightning.force.com';
    buildo.scopes = new List<String>();
    buildo.scopes.add('Full');
    buildo.scopes.add('RefreshToken');
    build.oauthConfig = buildo;
    List<MetadataService.UpsertResult> buildresults = service.upsertMetadata(
          new MetadataService.Metadata[] { build });


  }
}
```

When I try to use it with comand in console, i have this error :

```
FATAL_ERROR System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 586433682-45351 (1280375022) faultcode=sf:UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION faultactor=
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: I would try taking out the consumer key and consumer secret, since those aren't going to change anyways and they aren't writeable. Maybe that's what is throwing an error